# Try catch condition while combining CSV files in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am combining multiple csv files into a single dataframe using this line -

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, files), ignore_index=True)
```

I was earlier using a `for` loop where I combine two dataframes at time. This allowed me to use `try-catch` statements to catch any errors arising from empty/badly formatted csv files. But with the single-line command presented at the top, how do I enter a similar `try-catch` condition?

Comment: why dont you create a function that uses `pd.read_csv` and has try catch and map ur `files` to that function. It is not clear, what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Whats the error you're trying to catch ?

Comment: @Umar.H EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']

def readcsv(path):
    try:
        dff = pd.read_csv(path)
    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        print('error')
        dff = pd.DataFrame([]) #or anything else when error happen
        #I put empty dataframe here so the concat don't fail, but you can decide the behaviour you want when error happen (concat will fail if error happens...)
    return dff

df = pd.concat(map(readcsv, files), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I wanted it to ignore the individual files that generate the error and concatenate the valid csv files.

Comment: then you return empty dataframe ```pd.DataFrame([])``` when error happen, try it and let me know if worked